# folder's content as makefile rule dependency

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I would like to have all folder's content in dependency. My folder is created when the rule is called.

```
create-content:
 mkdir -p sample_dir/subdir1
 touch sample_dir/file1
 touch sample_dir/subdir1/file2

list-content: create-content $(shell find sample_dir)
 echo $^
```

I would like this output:

```
 make list-content
 create-content sample_dir sample_dir/file1 sample_dir/subdir1 sample_dir/subdir1/file2
```

But I have:

```
make list-content
create-content
```

The problem is that the `shell` function is called on `make` and not when the rule is running.
So `shell` is called before `create-content`, so the directory doesn't exist yet.
Is it possible to solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: I think I remember reading that using $$ instead of $ would make it evaluate later but I'm not sure and can't test it myself just this minute.

Comment: No I already tried with '.SECONDEXPANSION:', but it don't work...

Comment: how about an empty rule -> list-content : create-content list-content-impl 
That should make the second expansion be done after the create content has run, I think.

Comment: No, I tried but it don't work...

Comment: @FrankM The second expansion takes place after the first one but still before the target-update phase. So no, second expansion is not a solution to this problem because what the OP wants is an expansion **after** a recipe has been run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no... and yes.

No, you can't because make builds all its dependency graph before it runs the first recipe. So, if a recipe creates new nodes of the dependency graph, it is too late for make to notice.

But there is a simple workaround: tell make to invoke make (recursive make). Despite what many people say, recursive make is not always harmful. It is even sometimes the only solution to a specific problem. This is your case. And with a bit of make magic (conditionals) you can hide this with two different behaviors depending on the existence of `sample_dir`:

```
create-content:
    @mkdir -p sample_dir/subdir1 && \
    touch sample_dir/file1 && \
    touch sample_dir/subdir1/file2

ifeq ($(wildcard sample_dir),)
list-content: create-content
    @$(MAKE) --no-print-directory $@
else
list-content: create-content $(shell find sample_dir)
    @echo $^
endif
```

Now, the prerequisites of `list-content` are complete. Demo:

```
$ rm -rf sample_dir
$ make list-content
create-content sample_dir sample_dir/file1 sample_dir/subdir1 sample_dir/subdir1/file2
$ make list-content
create-content sample_dir sample_dir/file1 sample_dir/subdir1 sample_dir/subdir1/file2
```

Comment: Okay, this is I wanted to know, if is it possible or no! Thank you for your tricks!